# iphone css help

Tags: iphone, css

I want to make css for iphone ..  but I cant..  for example I make a div and gave it width:320 and height: 480px then join from iphone blabla.html.. it look too small

I want full screen (320x480)

sample picture..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is to add this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

You should read about viewport and screen sizes, for instance [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) as well as [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).